# Java how to add a label inside to a TextField (or TextArea)

Tags: label, textfield

I am want to know if it is possible to add a label inside in a textfield or textarea.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_sudoku#mediaviewer/File:Killersudoku_color.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_sudoku#mediaviewer/File%3aKillersudoku_color.svg)

check this image. You can notice that there are numbers in the top left corner, but you can still enter numbers in the cells.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may try for background image for respective textfield as :

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField(5);  
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Test.gif"));  
label.setOpaque(true);  
label.setBackground(tf.getBackground());
```